# Is there a "fundamental theorem of toric geometry"?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, toric-varieties, fans

I have some questions about toric geometry.
 1) Can *any* toric variety (I mean not necessarily smooth or projective, ...) be constructed from a fan ?
 2) Suppose $T_1$ and $T_2$ are toric varieties coming from fans $F_1$ and $F_2$ in (say) $\mathbb{R}^2$. Is there a theorem saying something like "$T_1$ and $T_2$ are isomorphic if and only if $F_1$ and $F_2$ are, by an element of (for instance - just to set the stage) $\mathbf{GL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$" ?
3) If so, does it generalize to higher dimensions as well ?

Thanks so much !

Comment: 1) Only normal toric varieties come from fans. 2) Yes, the toric data can be recovered from the Cox ring of the toric variety, which is an intrinsic invariant of the underlying variety.

Comment: If you are reading Fulton's book, toric varieties are defined to be normal. Other sources may differ.